# Correlation between variables

Tags: correlation, probability

Given **n** random variables **x1,...,xn** (one-dimensional). 
The following is known (corr() = Pearson correlation):

```
corr(x1,x2) = a
corr(x2,x3) = a
```

The actual values of the random variables are unkown though. Only some of their correlations are known.

From this, is it possible to calculate

```
corr(x3,x1) = ?
```

Or more generally, if the set of correlations `corr(x_i, x_i+1)` with `i=[1..c], c<(n-1)` are known, is it possible to estimate or directly calculate `corr(x_1, x_c+1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this answer on [quant.SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/531/848). I think it answers your question exactly.

Comment: The problem is almost identical to my question except one important fact: I do not have access to the covariances. And as a consequence, I'm not able to compute the lower bound as suggested on quant SE.

Comment: sry, misread the post on quant SE. It says correlation matrix, and not covariance matrix (which is what i thought).